# .net web app runs in VS, but gets 404 in IIS, generates wrong URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a .net 4.6.2 MVC application called Facility that runs fine in Visual Studio, but fails in IIS.  On document ready, the browser runs a bunch of functions like this:

```
function getInspectionEvents() {
    $.get("/Inspection/GetInspectionEvents", function (data) {
        model.inspection.removeAll();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            model.inspection.push(data[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

In f12 > Network I see a bunch of 404 errors.  The requests it complains about all leave out the name of the app, Facility. e.g.:

Should be:
https://(server)/Facility/Inspection/GetInspectionEvents

Is:
https://(server)/Inspection/GetInspectionEvents

How do I fix this?

I tried changing the get to:

```
$.get("/Facility/Inspection/GetInspectionEvents")
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make an AJAX request to an `https` page if you are currently in http because of the Same Origin Policy.

> The host, port and scheme (protocol) must be the same in order for the AJAX request to work.

If not making a cross-domain request, you may try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: "https://(server)/Facility/Inspection/GetInspectionEvents",
    success: function(data){
        // --- your code here
             }
});
```

Otherwise, implement [CORS (cross-origin resource sharing)](https://jakeydocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/cors.html) on the target domain to permit this particular request.